# Como fazer gráficos de previsão no R?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Tenho um modelo que faz previsões e gostaria de plotar a série observada e depois as previsões, de acordo com esse gráfico:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tentei utilizar o `geom_smooth` junto com o `geom_line`, mas sem sucesso, fica retornando erro.

Código que estou utilizando:

```
#remotes::install_github("joachim-gassen/tidycovid19")
library(tidyverse)
library(openxlsx)
library(tidycovid19)

previsoes <- read.xlsx("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/gabrielrvsc/COVID19_outputs/master/forecasts_20200513.xlsx")
previsoes$Data <- convertToDate(previsoes$Data)

updates <- download_merged_data(cached = TRUE)

updates %>%
  filter(iso3c %in% "BRA", date > "2020-03-20") %>%
  ggplot() +
  geom_line(aes(x = date, y = confirmed)) +
  geom_line(previsoes, aes(x = Data, y = Previsao_Casos))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eu testei seu código aqui e o erro que apareceu foi

> Erro: Mapping should be created with `aes() or`aes_()`.

Para corrigir isso, você precisa declarar 'data'

```
geom_line(data = previsoes, aes(x = Data, y = Previsao_Casos))
```

OBS. Seu gráfico não ficará como o que você pede pois os dados em 'previsões' só tem maio, a partir de 14/05. Fica uma falha na linha pois falta dia 14/05 no 'updates'. Ele pula por causa do NA

> Removed 1 row(s) containing missing values (geom_path).

Você terá que tratar esse NA para ele juntar as linhas

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

OBS.: 
Refiz o código criando data frames para organizar melhor, corrigir falhas na plotagem e conseguir plotar legendas, etc.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(openxlsx)
library(tidycovid19)

previsoes <- read.xlsx("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/gabrielrvsc/COVID19_outputs/master/forecasts_20200513.xlsx")
previsoes$Data <- convertToDate(previsoes$Data)

updates <- download_merged_data(cached = TRUE)

df1 <- updates %>%
   filter(iso3c %in% "BRA", date > "2020-03-20") %>%
   select(date, confirmed) %>% 
   rename(Data = date, Casos = confirmed) %>% 
   mutate(Tipo = "Confirmados")

df2 <- previsoes %>% 
   select(Data, Previsao_Casos) %>% 
   rename(Casos = Previsao_Casos) %>% 
   mutate(Tipo = "Previsto")

df3 <- rbind(df1, df2)

options(scipen = 999)

grafico <- df3 %>%  
   ggplot() +
   geom_line(aes(x = Data, y = Casos, linetype = Tipo)) +
   geom_vline(xintercept = as.Date("2020-05-14"), lty = 2) +
   scale_x_date(date_breaks = "7 days", date_labels = "%d/%b") +
   geom_ribbon(data = previsoes, aes(x = Data, ymin = Previsao_Casos-Previsao_Casos_Variacao, ymax = Previsao_Casos+Previsao_Casos_Variacao), alpha = 0.3)
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Obrigado! Mas como coloco aquelas linhas pontilhadas na vertical sinalizando que trata-se de uma projeção e o desvio-padrão em cinza? O desvio-padrão está sinalizado nas colunas ```Previsao_Casos_LB``` e ```revisao_Casos_UB```.

Comment: para a linha vertical, você pode usar abline para isso! Dê uma olhada na documentação. Se não conseguir, me avise que eu tento aqui com vc!

Comment: Consegui usar o ```geom_abline```, como faço pra adicionar os intervalos de confiança?

Comment: Eu não entendi exatamente seus dados, as variáveis, mas testa adicionar essa linha e aí vc trabalha com ela: `geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = Previsao_Casos-Previsao_Casos_Variacao, ymax = Previsao_Casos+Previsao_Casos_Variacao), alpha = 0.3)`

Comment: Esse sombreado que o `geom_smooth` faz, ele próprio calcula a partir da dispersão dos dados. No seu caso, vc não está plotando "pontos dispersos", ele segue uma numeração exata dia-a-dia e a variação já está calculada. O ribbon permite que vc indique essa variação

Comment: O ``geom_ribbon```funcionou perfeitamente, sabe me dizer como faço para plotar a legenda? Obrigado por toda a disponibilidade

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108046/discussion-between-americo-neto-and-alexandre-sanches).